# GKScore.report completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift, game-center-leaderboard

I am uploading scores to Game Center leaderboards, but my completion handler code doesn't seem to work, yet compiles:

```
   func submitScore(_ score : Int, _ ID : String) {

    let leaderboardID = ID
    let sScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: leaderboardID)
    sScore.value = Int64(score)
    print(3)
    GKScore.report([sScore], withCompletionHandler: { (error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("fail")
        }
        else {
            print("Score submitted")

        }
    } as? (Error?) -> Void)
}
```

With a valid leaderboard ID, 3 is printed, but nothing else. The same happens with an invalid ID. What is wrong?